# Change Select to Input with 2 Button

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to change a select element in a form with 2 checkboxes.

If box 1 is checked then the select will be active, if box 2 is checked then the select should change to a textinput.

It is important that every field must be left clear after they leave.

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
function fun1() {
var xx = document.getElementById('radio1');
if(xx==1)
{
    document.getElementById('textin').style.display = "block";
}
else if(xx==2)
{
    document.getElementById('selectin').style.display = "block";
}
else
{
}}
</script>



<form  method="post"  name="multiform" id="form8" action="">
<label>Formular</label><br>

<input id="textin" type="text" placeholder="test1">

<select id="selectin">
<option ></option>
<option value="6">item 6</option>
<option value="7">item 7</option>
<option value="8">item 8</option>
<option value="9">item 9</option>
</select>
</form>

<input id="radio1" type="radio" name="select" value="1" checked>INPUT Text
<input id="radio1" type="radio" name="select" value="2">SELECT from
```

Comment: Hey bruno, and welcome. StackOverflow is a helpful resource for debugging *specific* issues, however your question lacks any attempts or research for us to debug. Because of this, it reads as if you're looking for someone to write the code for you, which is frowned upon. Instead, do some research and make an attempt of your own. Once you've gotten a ways along and have *specific* questions, we'd love to help out. As they say - help *us* help *you*!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my approach. I took some freedom and formatted your HTML to be more semantic, and put notes on the script. Feel free to ask if something is not clear.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <body>
        <form method="post" name="multiform" id="form8" action="" onchange="toggleRadio();">
            <label for="radio1">INPUT Text</label>
            <input id="radio1" type="radio" name="select" checked />
            <label for="radio2">SELECT from</label>
            <input id="radio2" name="select" type="radio" />
            <label id="textLabel" for="textin">Formular
                <input id="textin" type="text" placeholder="test1" />
            </label>
            <label id="selectLabel" for="selectin">Items
                <select id="selectin">
                  <option selected></option>
                  <option value="6">item 6</option>
                  <option value="7">item 7</option>
                  <option value="8">item 8</option>
                  <option value="9">item 9</option>
                </select>
            </label>
        </form>
        <script>
function toggleRadio() { // will activate when the form will change.
    var radio1 = document.getElementById('radio1'); // radio 1
    var radio2 = document.getElementById('radio2'); // radio 2
    if (radio1.checked == true) { // if the first checked display input and hide select
        document.getElementById('textLabel').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('selectLabel').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('selectin').selectedIndex = 0; // clear selected option
    }
    else { // because you got only 2 option you don't have to use another condition
        document.getElementById('textLabel').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('selectLabel').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('textin').value = ''; // clear input
    }
}
toggleRadio(); // call the function
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Good luck!

Comment: Hi Meshu thank you, that works fine, but the fields are not empty after change. So the hidden field must be empty / value="" . I must send only 1 value with the form , input or select. If the hidden input or select have a value it will not work for me.

Comment: Check it now - added 2 lines on the conditions in order to clear it.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is almost right, you just need to tweak some change.

you select your radio box like this

```
var xx = document.getElementById('radio1');
```

but remember that your id reference just return the first element it find. 
Instate of doing that you need to select all of your radio box and add change event to them. then place your logic there.

Here is the modified `javascript` code

```
// select all of your radio box
var radio_boxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="select"]');
// then loop through all of your input element and add change event 
radio_boxes.forEach(function(radiobox){
   radiobox.addEventListener('change', checkForRadioboxChage);
});  


// this function will execute when radio box is changed. 
function checkForRadioboxChage(event){
   var value = event.target.value;
   if(value === "1"){
        hideAndShow(true);
   } else if(value === "2"){
        hideAndShow(false);
   }
}

// this function will hide and show the select and input box
function hideAndShow(isTextShow){
    var text_input = document.getElementById('textin'),
        select_input = document.getElementById('selectin');
    if(isTextShow){
        // display text input and hide select input
        text_input.style.display= "block";
        select_input.style.display = "none";
        // clear hidden input 
        select_input.value = "";
    } else {
       text_input.style.display= "none";
       select_input.style.display = "block";
       // clear hidden input 
       text_input.value = "";
    } 

}
```

Here is the `HTML` Code

```
<form  method="post"  name="multiform" id="form8" action="">
<label>Formular</label><br>

<input id="textin" type="text" placeholder="test1">

<select id="selectin" style="display: none;">
<option ></option>
<option value="6">item 6</option>
<option value="7">item 7</option>
<option value="8">item 8</option>
<option value="9">item 9</option>
</select>
</form>

<input id="radio1" type="radio" name="select" value="1" checked>INPUT Text
<input id="radio1" type="radio" name="select" value="2">SELECT from
```

I
I think that will help you to understand the workflow...